# Error occurred in deployment step 'Install Sharepoint Add-in': The parameter is Incorrect

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

While trying to deploy a SharePoint add-in to my SharePoint developer site, the error list shows "Error occurred in deployment step 'Install Sharepoint Add-in': The parameter is Incorrect (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057(E_INVALIDARG))". Despite this error, the app runs but not the way i expected and i want to rule out the error could be the cause. Tbf, i'm quite a noob to Sharepoint development and the error sometimes shows and sometimes doesn't. Also, the retract option within VS 2022 doesn't seem to work for 1 of my apps.

Things i've tried below which seemed to have had effect;

> Changed IIS Express to Local iis with corresponding ports (including changing them to the ports as defined in the web.config files
> Fresh deployed the solution
> Retracted app
> cleaned solution
> rebuilt solution